# install a specific version of winston package

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

is it possible to download specific version of winston through npm like below:
`npm install winston=2.2.0`

because on downloading the latest version i am facing the below issue with my existing code written in 2.2.0 :

```
(node:13100) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: cb is not a function
(node:13100) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `npm install winston@2.2.0`.

For more info, read the `npm install` docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install